# Geodesics on the intersection of linear surfaces

Tags: calculus-of-variations, geodesic

I've become interested in finding geodesic on the intersection of riemann manifolds however it turns out much of the literature is way above my head so I'm looking into simpler cases.

Suppose we have two distinct surfaces $U$ and $V$ in $R^3$ that intersect.  Since the surfaces are distinct and intersect the intersection must be a line.

If $A$ is a point on $U$ and $B$ is a point on $V$ how do you find the shortest path(s) between the points?

My inclination is that it boils down to a boundary value problem in the calculus of variations and finding the geodesic subject to the constraint that the end point is on the line of intersection but I cannot find a way to set the problem in general.

I would love help setting up the general problem or links to papers or articles that talk about this.  I have a feeling that there isn't any nice solution but I'm hoping that there are some simplifications.

EDIT:

I realized that the geodesic on a linear surface is just a straight line so this is just a matter of minimizing the distance between $A$ and the line of intersection plus the distance between $B$ and the line of intersection.

Comment: It would help if you could give a careful statement of a single, precise instance of the problem you're trying to solve. For example: "If $U$ and $V$ are non-parallel planes in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ and $A \in U \setminus V$, $B \in V \setminus U$, is there a unique shortest path in $U \cup V$ joining $A$ to $B$, and if so, where does this path hit $U \cap V$?" As written, I have no real idea what you're asking.

Comment: Your statement is what I was after but I ended up figuring it out.  I wasn't really concerned with uniqueness but I believe that the geodesic must be unique.  Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, in this situation a shortest path exists and is unique, and can be found by elementary geometry. (Calling the length-minimizing path a "geodesic" is potentially risky, since the union of two non-parallel planes isn't a manifold, and if you retain only the two closed half-planes containing $A$ and $B$, the union is not smooth along the line of intersection.)

Comment: I hadn't thought about the issues with calling it a geodesic.  Is there a better name for the curves that I care about.  In a more general sense is there a name for a curve the minimizes distance on the intersection of riemann manifolds?  There isn't any guarantee of existence or uniqueness there?